# KeyboardAvoidingView methods' description

Tags: react-native

I am trying to tailor KeyboardAvoidingView to my app. [The documentation of this component](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/keyboardavoidingview.html#methods) is rather horrible and I am having difficulties understanding what each method described on the page does, since there is literally no description on how to use them.

If you have used this Component, could you explain what do the methods above do and how to use them?

Comment: I +1 this, the documentation for the Methods is aweful. Did you ever figure this out?